# Remove word from url

Tags: bash, api, sed, openstack

I Need to remove `/%(tenant_id)s` from this source:

```
https://ext.an1.test.dev:8776/v3/%(tenant_id)s
```

To make it look like this:

```
https://ext.an1.test.dev:8776/v3
```

I'm trying through **sed**, but unsuccessfully.

`curl ....... | jq -r .endpoints[].url | grep '8776/v3' | sed -e 's/[/%(tenant_id)s] //g'`

I get it again:

```
https://ext.an1.test.dev:8776/v3/%(tenant_id)s
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the meaning of square brackets.

```
curl ....... |
jq -r '.endpoints[].url' |
sed -n '\;8776/v3;s;/%.*;;p'
```

fixes the incorrect regex, loses the [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep), and somewhat simplifies the processing by switching to a different delimiter. To protect against (fairly unlikely) shell wildcard matches on the text in the `jq` search expression, I also added single quotes around that.

In some more detail, `sed -n` avoids printing input lines, and the address expression `\;8776/v3;` selects only input lines which match the regex `8776/v3`; we use `;` as the delimiter around the regex, which (somewhat obscurely) requires the starting delimiter to be backslashed. Then, we perform the substitution: again, we use `;` as the delimiter so that slashes and percent signs in the regex do not need to be escaped. The `p` flag on the substitution causes `sed` to print lines where the substitution was performed successfully; we remove the `g` flag, as we don't expect more than one match per input line. The substitution replaces everything after the first occurrence of `/%` with nothing.

(Equivalently, with slash delimiters, you would have to backslash all literal slashes: `sed -n '/8776\/v3/s/\/%.*//p'`.)

For the record, square brackets in regular expressions form a *character class;* the expression `[abc]` matches a single character which can be one of `a`, `b`, or `c`. Perhaps review the tips on the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for a quick rerun on this and other common beginner mistakes.

Besides the incorrect square brackets, your regex specified a space after `s`, which is unlikely to be there. Other than that, your regex should work fine if you are sure the string you want to remove is always exactly `/%(tenant_id)s`. (Many regex dialects require round parentheses to be escaped, but `sed` without `-E` or `-r` is not one of those.)

Comment: You could also refactor all of this into `jq` which is a performance improvement but perhaps clunky; the `jq` custom language is somewhat quirky.

Answer (score 0):

If you've managed to get the address into a variable then one parameter expansion idea:

```
$ myaddr='https://ext.an1.test.dev:8776/v3/%(tenant_id)s'

$ echo "${myaddr%/*}"
https://ext.an1.test.dev:8776/v3

$ mynewaddr="${myaddr%/*}"
$ echo "${mynewaddr}"
https://ext.an1.test.dev:8776/v3
```

Comment: If you are going to use this URL later on in your script, this is a better solution than the `sed` approach in my answer.